# div collapsing auto height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a div collapsing with all of its content. i make it sucessfully.
here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Div Collapsing</title>
<style type="text/css">

#con{
width:60%;
height:60px;
background:#333;
overflow:hidden;
padding:5px;
}

#text{
margin:5px;
margin-top:20px;
height:auto;
background:#FFF;}

#myPlus{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:#FFF;
line-height:50px;
text-align:center;
font-size:36px;
cursor:pointer;}

@keyframes myCol{
from{height:60px;}
to{height:200px;}
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function my(){
     document.getElementById("con").style.height = "200px";
     document.getElementById("con").style.animationName = "myCol";
     document.getElementById("con").style.animationDuration = "1s";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="con">
   <div onclick="my();" id="myPlus" >+</div>
    <div id="text">
`Sample text<br />
Sample text<br />
Sample text<br />
Sample text<br />
Sample text<br />
Sample text<br />
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here when I click on + symbol then my `#con` div collapsed 200px, but I need to collapsed this div as much need for div `#text`. for example if the div `#text` need 500px then collapsed 500px, and if 100px then collapsed 1000px;
how to do it?

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot animate from `height: auto` to a specific pixel value.  If you're animating from `height: auto`, however, you can add this to the beginning of `my()`

```
var con = document.getElementById('con');
con.style.height = con.offsetHeight + 'px'
```